# Set VLAN mode on only one VNIC

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v, vlan

I'm setting up a [Sophos XG virtual appliance on Hyper-V](http://docs.sophos.com/nsg/sophos-firewall/vm-guides/Sophos%20XG%20Firewall%20Virtual%20Appliance%20-%20Getting%20Started%20Guide%20-%20Hyper-V.pdf) Server 2016 (Core) in a VLAN-ed network so the VLAN modes of the VNICs need to be configured so that the LAN interface will be a trunk port and the WAN interface will be untagged.

`Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan`'s default output suggests granularity:

```
VMName                      VMNetworkAdapterName Mode     VlanList
------                      -------------------- ----     --------
Sophos XG Virtual Appliance LAN                  Trunk    1000,1000-1090
Sophos XG Virtual Appliance WAN                  Trunk    1000,1000-1090
```

However, according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmnetworkadaptervlan?view=win10-ps and my experience and research, `Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan` simply can only be used to set the VLAN mode of **all** of the VNICs in a VM, rather than a specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this by setting the VLAN mode of the VM then re-adding the VNIC:

```
PS D:\VMs> Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -VMName "Sophos XG Virtual Appliance" -Trunk -AllowedVlanIdList 1000-1090 -NativeVlanId 1000
PS D:\VMs> Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan

VMName                      VMNetworkAdapterName Mode   VlanList
------                      -------------------- ----   --------
Sophos XG Virtual Appliance LAN                  Trunk  1000,1000-1090
Sophos XG Virtual Appliance WAN                  Trunk  1000,1000-1090


PS D:\VMs> Remove-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName "Sophos XG Virtual Appliance" -VMNetworkAdapterName "WAN"
PS D:\VMs> Add-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName "Sophos XG Virtual Appliance" -Name "WAN"
PS D:\VMs> Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName "Sophos XG Virtual Appliance" -Name "WAN" -SwitchName "Sophos XG WAN"
PS D:\VMs> Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan

VMName                      VMNetworkAdapterName Mode     VlanList
------                      -------------------- ----     --------
Sophos XG Virtual Appliance LAN                  Trunk    1000,1000-1090
Sophos XG Virtual Appliance WAN                  Untagged


PS D:\VMs>
```

There may well be a better way to do this and if there is then I'd love to know but I wasn't able to find it.